# Django how do we send a model into javascript and render it onto a template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm trying to pass a Django model into a template using javascript.
I can't seem to filter or do anything with the QuerySet once I get the javascript to read it and pass it on to the template.

My views.py:

```
def displayDict(request):
    m = ChatStream.objects.filter(name = visitor_ip_address(request))
    last = m.latest('name')
    return render(request, 'chatStream.html',
    {"chat": m, "last": last})
```

my models.py:

```
class ChatStream(models.Model):
    bot = models.TextField()
    user = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My chatStream.html file:

```
<p id="demo2">I will display when two seconds have passed.</p>

<script>
    var data = "{{chat}}";
    var lastEntry = "{{last}}"
    } 

setTimeout(myTimeout1, 2000) 


function myTimeout2() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "2 seconds " + data + "lastEntry" + lastEntry;
}

</script>
```

The result I get after 2 seconds:

> 2 seconds <QuerySet [<ChatStream: ChatStream object (31)>,
> <ChatStream: ChatStream object (32)>]>lastEntryChatStream object (31)

Instead of showing "<QuerySet [<ChatStream: ChatStream object (31)>....] "
**How do I show the text inside the model named ChatStream?...**

I've tried:

```
<p id="demo2">I will display when two seconds have passed.</p>

<script>
    var data = "{{chat.user}}";
    var lastEntry = "{{last.user}}"
    } 

setTimeout(myTimeout1, 2000) 


function myTimeout2() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "2 seconds " + data + "lastEntry" + lastEntry;
}

</script>
```

But the above displays nothing.

I've also tried

```
<p id="demo2">I will display when two seconds have passed.</p>

<script>
    var data = "{{chat | last }}";
    var lastEntry = "{{last}}"
    } 

setTimeout(myTimeout1, 2000) 


function myTimeout2() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "2 seconds " + data + "lastEntry" + lastEntry;
}

</script>
```

but filtering in last throws an error that I can't negative index (and I have the latest version of Django running).

Thanks so much

Comment: If you provide your views here, I can give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Hills -- I've added views and models

Comment: `m` is a queryset of objects, so you need to loop over the queryset to get each one of them, and then inside it you can do `chat.user` etc. Either in the view or in the template. If you pass along this queryset to the template you can do `{% for my_query in my_queryset %} {{ my_query.user }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Thanls @Hills. I understand how to render a model within html, but more challenging for me is using this javascript function where the information appears after 2 seconds using the setTimeout() function

Comment: The text you are after are inside a object inside your queryset of objects. I would not put template tags inside of a js script. Instead you can create a partial template and then fetch it using get and then add the response where you want it in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChatStream.objects.filter(...)` returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) which is a **list** of objects of the ChatStream model, not a **single** ChatStream model object.

If you want to retrieve a single object of the ChatStream model the use

```
m = ChatStream.objects.get(name=visitor_ip_address(request))
```

Comment: Thanks @Sumithran: I'm trying to pass the model in as a variable to a javascript function so that there's a 2 second delay until the model's object gets rendered. How might I do what you suggest within javascript?

Comment: Your question was how do I show the text right, with the chage i suggested you can use     ```var data = "{{chat}}"; var lastEntry = "{{last}}"; ``` inside your template to show the text data..

Comment: OK got it @Sumithran! One question, I'm getting an error using ```m = ChatStream.objects.get(name=visitor_ip_address(request))```. The error is ```MultipleObjectsReturned 
get() returned more than one ChatStream -- it returned 3!``` ..... how would I isolate the entry to the very last entry?

Comment: Do you have multiple ChatStream objects with name=Visitor_ip ?? that can cause this error

Comment: When you insert data into a chat stream object make sure only one chat model exists with the given name that's how you solve this. or if you want to keep multiple name you should find a logic to select a single instance.. for eg: select one ChatStream obj with name equals current user or something like that,, you got it?

Comment: yeah! thanks for help